# Understanding and correcting the structure of Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I've been on here for awhile, and I'm still considered an entry level programmer based on my general knowledge of structure and basic concepts. I have a function below that was given to me in an answer for a different question I asked. I can understand most of what it is doing, but I need help understanding the rest of what it does. I'm asking this because I would really like to understand further advanced concepts of javascript, and jQuery.

So what I've done below is placed the function, and I'll comment in what I know about what the function is doing at where, and then I'll place question marks where I"m confused.

```
function validate(){
    //array of objeccts used to defined the class selector for each element iterated
    //with what validation function is be assigned to that specific selector
    var fields = [
        {
            selector: $('.not-empty'),
            validations: [ isNotEmpty]
        },
        {
            selector: $('.email'),
            validations: [ isNotEmpty, isEmail]
        },
        {
            selector: $('.number'),
            validations: [ isNotEmpty, isNumber]
        },
        {
            selector: $('.number-noreq'),
            validations: [isNumberNotRequired]
        },
        {
            selector: $('.checked'),
            validations: [isChecked]
        }
    ];
    //remove any classes of 'has-error' from each element traversed before validation begins
    $('.form-control').closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    //defining variables
    var i = 0, k = 0, z = 0, j = fields.length, item, selector, fn, info;
    //for loop to traverse the fields array of objects
    for(; i < j; i++){
        item = fields[i];
        //traversing each field.validation
        for(k = 0; k < item.validations.length; k++){
            fn = item.validations[k]; //setting fn as a function found in validation
            //traversing each selector in item
            for( z = 0; z < item.selector.length; z++){
                selector = $(item.selector[z]); //setting the selector
                //attempting to set info to the closest form or input group found by the selector
                info = selector.closest('.form-group, .input-group');
                if(info) //if info contains data
                    //?????????????????????????????????????? no idea what's going on below other
                    //other than it's running the validation function that was passed, but why
                    //is it written like this and what is it doing?
                    info[fn(selector.val()) ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']('has-error');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So that is the basic question I have for this code (where all the question marks are). If someone can clearly answer what is going on, why you write the code like that, what the purpose of it is, and is it benefcial or not, would be fantastic. if you need more clarification I would be happy to provide it. I just want to be able to explain the code to somebody and know what I am talking about instead of trying to have to bs my through it. I think it was Einstein who said, "If you can't explain something accurately and to the point, then you truly do not understand it" or something like that!

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: here are the functions that 'validations' traverse through

```
//validation functions
function isNotEmpty(value){
    return value && $.trim(value).length > 0;
}
function isEmail(value){
    return /^([^@\s\t\n]+\@[\w\d]+\.[\w]{2,3}(\.[\w]{2})?)$/.test(value);
}

function isNumber(value){
    return /^\d+$/.test(value);   
}
function isNumberNotRequired(value){
    return /^\d+$/.test(value) || value.length < 1;
}
 function isChecked(value){
    var r = false;
    var name = $(value).attr('name');
    $('input[name="'+name+'"').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        r = true;       
    }
    });
    return r;
}
```

SECOND EDIT/UPDATE: We have determined that there is a severe error in the code that allows it not to keep track of the validation and take into account previous validations for input groups, and other related sections. How does this corrected. I'm testing items on jsfiddle at the moment I will return when I have restuls!

Comment: The code is broken. Checking `if (info)` there will **always** be true, because the `.closest()` function will always return an object. It should be `if (info.length)`.

Comment: I know that it's not broken, it's taking the selector and running it through one of the functions in fields.validations and checking the results from one of those.

Comment: It may be hard to accept, but I assure you  that that code is wrong. The call to `selector.closest()` will **always** return an object, so that test in the `if` will **always** succeed. Now, maybe it's OK that it always succeeds, but if so it's unnecessary.

Comment: it's looks to basically be a "let's try and be cute" version of `if info.hasClass('has-error') { info.removeClass('has-error') } else { info.addClass('has-error'); }`

Comment: `fn(selector.val()) ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass'` if `fn(selector.val())` resolves as true, then the jQuery function `removeClass()` is run on that element. It's basically a mini if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
   info[fn(selector.val()) ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']('has-error');
```

is equivalent to this:

```
   var result = fn(selector.val());
   if (result)
     info.removeClass("has-error");
   else
     info.addClass("has-error");
```

How is that?  Well, your code calls the function plucked from the list of validation routines stored in that data structure, passing the value of the field to be tested. The result of that function call is used as a true/false test in the `? :` expression.  If the result is `true`, the `? :` resolves to the string `"removeClass"`; if `false`, to `"addClass"`.

Now, what is `info`?  It's a jQuery object that refers to the closest piece of the DOM that (presumably) is where an error message would be displayed, or where some other indicator would be shown based on some CSS rule. The `[ ]` operator will take whichever of those two strings the `? :` resolves to and use that as a property accessor.  The net effect, therefore, is to reference either `info.removeClass` or `info.addClass`. Those are both references to jQuery methods, so one or the other will be called. In either case, the code wants to operate on the class name "has-error", because it wants to either add it (when the validation fails) or remove it (when the validation succeeds).

That said, the code has a serious defect: if, for a given field, there is in fact a list of validation functions, the code will run all of them (which is fine). However, for each validation function, it sets or clears that "has-error" class *without regard to prior validation results*.  That *might* work, if you're really careful with the ordering of the validation functions, but that's an awfully fragile way of doing things. I think it would be much more robust if it made each test and kept track of whether *any* test failed, and then after that process is complete for a given field it'd only then set or clear the "has-error" class.

Fixing the code isn't too hard. Currently it iterates the the validation functions outside the iteration over the selected fields, which (I think) is backwards. However, as long as it checks the state of the error indicator element(s), it should be OK.

First, at the top, the code removes "has-error" from `.form-group` elements but not from `.input-group` elements. That's clearly incorrect, so:

```
$('.form-control').closest('.form-group, .input-group').removeClass('has-error');
```

Then, in the loop:

```
        for( z = 0; z < item.selector.length; z++){
            selector = $(item.selector[z]); //setting the selector
            //attempting to set info to the closest form or input group found by the selector
            info = selector.closest('.form-group, .input-group');
            if (info.length && !fn(selector.val())) // if info contains data and field is invalid
               info.addClass('has-error');
        }
```

Since all the "has-error" flags are cleared at the outset, all we need to do is *add* the class to classes that are invalid. If you wanted to have a positive "is-ok" class, then you'd add that to everything at the top and remove it when you find an error.

Comment: Sorry for the back-and forth edits; something must be wrong with my coffee this morning

Comment: Ha it's fine, i'm still waking up myself XD I'm blaring Andrew W.K. in my headphones at work to wake me up! So when you place a higher-order function inside of x[] like above, that assigns x as an object, so you can do x.fn etc.... ?is that a way to explain it?

Comment: @MarkHill I added some verbage; however I think there may be another issue with the code. I'm still staring at it.

Comment: no the code validates just fine. What I'm trying to figure out is how to edit it so that I can pass a single element as a paramenter, and check it for a class in the fields list, if the class exists proceed to validate, then all the way to the end, I want to either have it add has-error or has-success

Comment: @MarkHill yes that's precisely what I was trying to determine.

Comment: okay so now to step 2, after reading your last part of the edit, how do we make this work? I've been stumped on this since yesterday, if I can figure out how to rig this code right then I can finish my task in a few hours. Also this causes problems like for phone numbers, because it validates one section but if the second second has a letter and the last section is all numbers, it considers that phone number valid

Answer (score 2):

As you should have known, `foo.bar` are `foo["bar"]` are identical in JavaScript (if you did not know, learn it, now).

This line

```
info[fn(selector.val()) ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']('has-error');
```

means

```
var methodName;
if (fn(selector.val())) { methodName = 'removeClass'; } else { methodName = 'addClass'; }
info[methodName]('has-error')
```

so, in yet another words,

```
if (fn(selector.val())) {
   info.removeClass('has-error');
} else {
   info.addClass('has-error');
}
```

So it is actually switching class `has-error` on/off. Just it's pretty densely written.